# Broken German Umlaut ü

Tags: font-encodings, german

I worte a letter in scrlttr2 but finally had to write an email. Thus I copied the text from the PDF I already got. The spell checker of the mail client complained on some words – the ones containing the small German Umlaut ü. The ü is split into a u and a trema. The capital Ü as well as all other Umlaute work fine.

The problem occures even in the following minimal example (as in the original letter no fancy font, just cm-super):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
für Grüße Prüfungsbescheid
\xfonttable{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

Now, tracking down the problem, I looked at the font table. For ü t1enc.def and t1enc.dfu point to the character at 252/00FC. This letter is ü in the table, however, copying it from the font table reveals it contains a u and a trema (btw, similar situation for French ligature oe and OE in the table which becomes obvious on copying it to a text editor).

As far as I know, each character in a font table is one character. Why is only this character split up? Is there some way to unity u and trema to a ü?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it might be an idea to state which PDF viewer you are copying from. I have no issues copying the `für...` line from the PDF generated from your MWE, using Evince on Linux, generating the PDF using TeXLive 2018. Pasting the the text into any of my editors etc gives me the correct URF8 chars.

Comment: I'm using MacTeX 2018 and the issue occures in Adobe Acrobat Reader as well as in Preview.

Comment: How did you save your file (is it in UTF8)? You should check that, because some editors might save in another encoding which you need to specify using `inputenc`.

Comment: tex file is saved in utf8 and adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` doesn't change anything

Comment: the mac likes to split up such chars when copying and pasting. This is called decomposition and there is imho nothing you can do to prevent it.

Comment: Btw: the umlaut is not broken, that is a valid representation of the umlaut in unicode. But it is quite annoying in latex as pdflatex can't handle it as input.

Comment: Ah, so there is another interesting 'feature' Apple introduces for preventing work from becoming boring …

Comment: But why only ü? ä, ö, Ä, Ö, Ü work fine

Comment: Perhaps it is the only one it recognize. What happens if you add `\input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1`. Is it worse (more decomposed chars) or better? And imho the feature is there to get valid filenames: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83935/unicode-normalization-for-filenames-and-copied-text-from-pdfs

Comment: Neither better nor worse, it's still only the ü

Comment: I can't reproduce on my Mac. Tried Preview, Acrobat Reader and Skim.

Comment: Try two things: (1) Add Ää öÖ, ß, ffi, fl to your MWE that you provided here (and not to another file we can't check!) -- (2) add `\usepackage{cmap}` right after the line `\documentclass..` . Results?